# Why does the overloaded plus operator doesn't type check with my union type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, operator-overloading, overloading

When `x`/`y` are of type `Foo<any>` the expression `x + y` type checks. However, within `append` it doesn't type check. Why?

```
type Foo<A> = string | number;

function eq(x: Foo<number>): (y: Foo<number>) => boolean;
function eq(x: Foo<string>): (y: Foo<string>) => boolean {
    return y => {
        if (typeof x === "number")
            return x === y;

        else
            return x === y;
    }
}

const append = (x: Foo<any>) => (y: Foo<any>): Foo<any> => x + y;
//                                                         ^^^^^ type error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAQQHxQLxQM7AE4CWAdgOZQA+URArgLYBGEeA3ALABQHAZtUQMbACcIlAgBHABQAPAFywEiGgyaoAlHIkg58JEsZ41mdPQQAbCAEMibdj36DhoybPlJchUmo1bXid8RJDDGMzSxEAbw4oaKg8CGBqPBEQIyhI9hjMqAIuKAlQSDhcqUwMLAAiPSZy1Sis+riEpKgSsqwQGzr6iFNsCC76mMbEkVayqA6BgF8OGc52PmFcKAswSCIAE0w8lx1EKxAg9E1tBQOvX3PUkoBqCZsgA)

Comment: Not necessarily a generics issue, the union `string | number` is generally not considered to have the `+` operator:https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgBwQUzAExgXhgCgB4BcM0ATgJZgDmMAPjGAK4C2ARsiQJRYB8uAnkVIVqdRq3YdBUclVr1mbEjxh4YAahh8A3EA

Comment: When I drop the function abstraction it works though [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=4&pc=7#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHgLhtATgSzAcxgHxmAVwFsAjAUxRgF4YAmAbgFgAoUSWATyVQ2z0NIVqMAEQAzECBFNmLODADUMDvSA)

Comment: Only because the variables can be determined by CFA to be either `string` or `number` add some uncertainty and you get the same result: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHgLhtATgSzAcxgHxmAVwFsAjAUxRgF4YBZAQygAsA6FesAExCIAoBKGAD4YABhYBWGAH4YAIjlIATAG4AsAChQkWAE8kqDNjyFSFanUat2XHgOFjJMmEpgI5AMxAg56jZrgYAGoYXRUgA

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir can you tell me what CFA refers to? I find a few possibilities. My guess is "Control Flow Analysis" but I'm not sure. I'd like to find out more about this.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah Control Flow Analysis is the right one :) Sorry for the acronyms

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir no worries. I assume it's common thing, I just hadn't heard about it and couldn't narrow it down with a simple search. There is also something (presumably different) called "Continuous flow analysis" and also "Component failure analysis" that sort of sounded related. Or at least not outright unrelated. I wasn't sure if there wasn't another concept, as well. At any rate, thank you :) I was interested in how you actually derive types, so that seemed relevant.